# Android Studio: у эмулятора пустой экран

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Создал в Android Studio учебный проект Greeting Card, который показывает текст вроде Hello World на экране. Пытаюсь запустить его под эмулятором. Судя по выводу в консоль - всё успешно запускается, но экран эмулятора почему-то совершенно пустой. Не видно даже рамки экрана и интерфейса Андроида.
В консоли среди прочей информации есть такая строчка:

```
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
```

Возможно эта проблема как-то связана с этим сообщением?
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём тут может быть дело и как решить эту проблему?

Операционная система: Windows 10
Версия Android Studio: Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Полный текст вывода в консоль:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:60043', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/e.greetingcard: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
E/e.greetingcard: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
W/e.greetingcard: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.greetingcard2 is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10134(com.example.greetingcard2) identical 2 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1430)
D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:49): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=6952 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdf9cc8f0, tid 7565
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdf9c4540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf9c4540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf90f5c0)
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdf9cca30, tid 7565
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ff807000 size 0x2000
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdf9c4540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdf90f5c0)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.example.greetingcard2
```

Как выглядит окно эмулятора:

[image: Как выглядит окно эмулятора]